# Keeping only lines that follow a certain pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file with 5.5 million lines.

Example:

```
chr1    10000   10468   +   (TAACCC)n   Simple_repeat   Simple_repeat
chr1    10468   11447   -   TAR1    Satellite   telo
chr1    11504   11675   -   L1MC5a  LINE    L1
chr1    11677   11780   -   MER5B   DNA hAT-Charlie
chr10_GL383545v1_alt    11877   11980   -   Alu ERV1
chr11_BL383595v1_alt    12077   12980   -   Alu ERV1
chr3    11504   11675   -   L1MC5a  LINE    L1
```

I'm interested in keeping only the rows that do not have `_` in the first column

The output would be something like:

```
chr1    10000   10468   +   (TAACCC)n   Simple_repeat   Simple_repeat
chr1    10468   11447   -   TAR1    Satellite   telo
chr1    11504   11675   -   L1MC5a  LINE    L1
chr1    11677   11780   -   MER5B   DNA hAT-Charlie
chr3    11504   11675   -   L1MC5a  LINE    L1
```

I do not know how many of my unwanted rows exist. I'd preferably like to use `awk` but normal bash commands are fine too.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried using sed?

Comment: I tried grep, and awk, unfortunately the awk version of `~ /chr*/` gets me everything even the _'s, and I couldn't find any grep examples I could modify to not include the _'s.

Comment: @ Alexej Magura, i've never worked with sed and don't really understand the syntax unfortunately.

Comment: `sed` or `awk` would be slow for these amounts of lines. You can use `grep` as follow  `grep  '^chr1\+[[:space:]]' filename`

Comment: @val0x00ff I probably should have included this, but the chromosome numbers range from 1-22 as well as X and Y. Thus I need to find a grep solution that deletes any row that includes a _ in the first column.

Comment: easiest definition in that case would be `awk '$1 !~ /_/' file`

Comment: with grep, `grep -v '^\S*_' file`

Comment: @Sundeep the awk line worked perfectly, I wasn't aware of the !~ operator so that should make it much easier for the future. Thank you! If you add it as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is best suited for dealing with columns

```
awk '$1 !~ /_/' file
```

`!~` allows to check if something doesn't match the pattern

With `grep`

```
grep -v '^\S*_' file
```

or, if `\S` is not recognized,

```
grep -v '^[^[:space:]]*_' file
```